# How to access a specific field of a json array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working with an API that returns arrays in json format. The code in json that is received is:

```
Array ([0] => Array ([phone] => 000123123 [_id] => 52e68920acfced017af80234 [name] => John [email] => john@gmail.com [country] => France) [1] => Array ([phone] => 111222333 [_id] => 52e68acas87fa0987a [name] => James [email] => james@gmail.com [country] => Germany))
```

I want to access each field of the json array in my php file to process data individually. For example, to access the name of first register, I use the following code:

```
$cuerpoRespuesta = ejecutarPOST($URLS['retrieve'], $api_id, $api_key, array()); // This is the API call and I keep the json array in "$cuerpoRespuesta". 

$data = json_decode($cuerpoRespuesta, TRUE); //Now I decode json array
echo $data[0]["name"];                       //Here I show data
```

But doesn't shows anything, I get the following error:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array Given in C:\Retrieve.php on line 65

Line 65 corresponds to json_decode. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I've tried the var_dump($cuerpoRespuesta) function and I get this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'phone' => string '000123123' (length=9)
      '_id' => string '52e68920acfced017af80234' (length=24)
      'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'john@gmail.com' (length=14)
      'country' => string 'France' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'phone' => string '000123123' (length=9)
      '_id' => string '52e68ac7acfced017af80235' (length=24)
      'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'john@gmail.com' (length=14)
      'country' => string 'France' (length=6)
```

According to the API documentation is Json, but... if it's not, I don't know what it is :/

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory: check what it is in `$cuerpoRespuesta` by issuing a `var_dump($cuerpoRespuesta)`, and check what is happening. By the way I advise you not to write code in native speech [in your case spanish], it makes harder to understand what you are doing across a wider audience like StackOverflow.

Comment: It looks like its not in JSON, so you shouldn't need to do json_decode.

Comment: Thanks both answers.

moonwave99, I don't know how to use "var_dump..." Can you explain this? Thanks a lot.

Phil, according to the API documentation I am using, the returned array is in JSON format. :/

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON array, you either have a string which can contain valid JSON or you have an array.

Comment: If it's not a JSON array? What is that? :/

And how I can access every fields individually? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the question with results about the var_dump function. I hope you can help me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your var_dump($cuerpoRespuesta), you already have your array, so you only have to access what you want. And you don't need json_decode your $cuerpoRespuesta var.

You can access your fields this way:

```
echo $cuerpoRespuesta[0]['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going crazy trying to decode a json that's not json. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Here: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [json functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Comment: Link-only hints can be posted as comments under the question.